# How do I get a POST request to work in Confluence REST API?

Tags: rest, api, post, postman, confluence

I'm trying to create a page in confluence, via the REST API. I can do GET requests on specific pages correctly, but when I POST a page to a specific Space I just get a 200 response, containing JSON that is the same as that returned from the same URL using a GET request. No page is created. I'm using Postman, and basic auth.

My POST request url looks like this:

```
http://myConfluence/rest/api/content/
```

The body of the request looks like this:

```
{
"type":"page",
"title":"Test API Page",
"space":{"key":"~myUsername"},
"body": {

"storage": {
  "value": "<p>This is a new page</p>",
  "representation": "storage"
  }
 }
}
```

In the JSON above, the space I'm using is my Home space, however I've tried with various other spaces to no avail. It seems unusual that I would be getting a 200 and the same results as a GET request, but on a POST request. Functionally the POST request seems to be acting as a GET request.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought: do you have actual permissions to create pages on Confluence? There might be a slight chance that you have RO access.

Comment: I'm able to create pages manually through the web page, for example in my home space (which ideally is where I'd like to be able to create pages through the API).

Comment: a GET on myConfluence/rest/api/accessmode confirms that I have "READ_WRITE" access

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else weirdly having the same issue, here was the fix:

I changed the URL from

```
http://myConfluence/rest/api/content/
```

To

```
https://myConfluence/rest/api/content/
```

Silly error that cost a lot of time.